# LLVM produced by rustc gives error about argument type of main when run with lli

Tags: rust, llvm, lli

I'm trying to learn a little about the LLVM IR, particularly what exactly rustc outputs. I'm having a little bit of trouble running even a very simple case.

I put the following in a source file `simple.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 7u32;
    let y = x + 2;
}
```

and run `rustc --emit llvm-ir simple.rs` to get the file `simple.ll`, containing

```
; ModuleID = 'simple.cgu-0.rs'
source_filename = "simple.cgu-0.rs"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN6simple4main17h8ac50d7470339b75E() unnamed_addr #0 {
start:
  br label %bb1

bb1:                                              ; preds = %start
  ret void
}

define i64 @main(i64, i8**) unnamed_addr {
top:
  %2 = call i64 @_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17ha09816a4e25587eaE(void ()* @_ZN6simple4main17h8ac50d7470339b75E, i64 %0, i8** %1)
  ret i64 %2
}

declare i64 @_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17ha09816a4e25587eaE(void ()*, i64, i8**) unnamed_addr

attributes #0 = { uwtable }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIE Level", i32 2}
```

I then try to run this with the command

```
lli-3.9 -load ~/.multirust/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-35ad9950c7e5074b.so simple.ll
```

but I get the error message

```
LLVM ERROR: Invalid type for first argument of main() supplied
```

I'm able to make a minimal reproduction of this as follows: I make a file called `s2.ll`, containing

```
define i32 @main(i64, i8**) {
    ret i32 42
}
```

and running `lli-3.9 s2.ll` gives the same error message. *But* if I change the contents of `s2.ll` to

```
define i32 @main(i32, i8**) {
    ret i32 42
}
```

(i.e. I've changed the type of `argc` in main) then `lli-3.9 s2.ll` runs, and `echo $?` reveals that it did indeed return `42`.

I don't think I should have to pass in the `i64` explicitly - my argument list or C strings should be put into memory somewhere and the pointer and length passed to `main` automatically, right? Therefore I assume that I'm doing something wrong in the way in invoke `lli` - but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 5):

Rust marks its entry point (the function marked with `#[start]` attribute, by default the function `lang_start` in the standard library) as taking an argc parameter of type `isize`. [This is a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29633) because it should have the type of a C int, so it should be 32 bits on a 64-bit platform, but `isize` is 64 bits. However, due to the way 64-bit calling conventions work, this happens to still work correctly. The same issue also exists for the return type.

[A fix](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/44906) for this has been committed on 2017-10-01 and should be present in Rust 1.22.

`lli` is apparently more strict about checking the type of `main` which is why it gives the error. But if you use `llc` instead, it should work correctly.

To get the correct `main` signature, you can cancel the default `main` by putting `#![no_main]` at the top of the module, and provide your own `main` marked with `#[no_mangle]`. But note that this will skip the standard library's initialization.

```
#![no_main]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn main(_argc: i32, _argv: *const *const u8) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

See also:

- [documentation about `lang_items` and disabling `main`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html)
- [Tracking issue for `#[start]` feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29633), where some people mention `isize` not being correct.